# What is the mechanism through which the computer name (hostname) is propagated through the local network and can be read by a network scanner?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking, android, hostname

So I have an android mobile phone which is connected to a WLAN. I used a Network scanner on my Android phone to detect other computers on the network and I was surprised to see that not only the app find other IPs connected to the network but also the computer names and other computers were running Windows. I fugured out that it might be some OS independent protocol that propagates the host names on a Local Area Network but I did not learn at school about it. What is the name of the protocol?

Answer (score 1):

Everything goes down to the name resolution approach used by the application. There are essentially two approaches via DNS or via NIS/NetBIOS. More information [here](http://www.logicmonitor.com/blog/2014/02/11/why-name-resolution-for-ping-may-disagree-with-dns/).